# Images needs to fit next to each other on every screen size

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to goof around with making a website about my favourite TV shows.

If you open the site you come on the starting page (duh) this page consist 7 images. Every images has a link to the website that tells something about the show.

But now comes my question: those 7 images from the starting page have a standard width. Now if you open the site in a smaller screen the images are not next to eachother anymore. So I want with diffrent screen sizes that the images stay next to eachother, is there a way to do this?

If you have a background you can use `background-size: cover`, but I don't use a background  I just want the images to be "responsive".

The [site](http://tvshows.zz.mu/)

Answer (score 1):

Give the image class height and width in %.

Here's a sample:

```
.image {
    float: left;
    height: 80%;
    width: 20%;
    display: block;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use percentages. You could try to find more info about responsive websites. They usually work this way.

Here some css for one possible solution:(you can clear the current css you have)

```
a {
  width: calc(100% / 7);
  float: left;
}
a img {
  display: block;// Probably not required, but just in case.
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;// Not required, just shows a bit better what's going on
}
```

Other options could be using tables(bad) or flexbox(fancy, but not too easy)

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add width for images

```
.image{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 14.2857143%; /* 100%/7 will work on all browsers*/
}
```

[image]